# jquery lazy load plugin not working on auto loading content

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I am using lazy load plugin to load my content but it is working fine for the content which is first to be loaded but when I try to load content dynamically from other file using Ajax
 it is showing me 
`typeerror: $("img.lazyimage").lazyload() is not a function`

here is my code for **jquery** lazy load

```
(function($)
{
    $("img.lazyimage").lazyload();
})(jQuery);
```

what might be the problem it is working fine on the content which is loaded first on loading the website

Answer (score 0):

With ajax is a bit different, have a look:

```
  (function() {
     $("#container").load("images.html", function(response, status, xhr) {
         $("img.lazyimage").lazyload();
     });              
    });
```

http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/lazyload/enabled_ajax.html